# Does Python have an interactive plot manipulation library similar to dygraphs?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently going through some time series analysis, and I'd like to easily implement interactive zoom and range selection.

I know [dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/range-selector) offers such features, and I'd like to know if there is a similar Library for Python?

Thanks

Comment: https://plot.ly/python/ has some of these, even in their 'offline' module

Comment: `matplotlib.widgets` has sliders and the likes, if that is of any help

Comment: `dygraphs` is way faster than plotly. However, it lacks support in Python. The R interface is better, I used it sometimes successfully with a huge amount of data.